# Javascript function works half the time

Tags: javascript, function

Okay, I know this is weird, and I thought maybe it has something to do with hoisting, but I don't really understand it so I'm not sure at all. 
I basically have a rock-paper-scissors game where if you don't choose anything the computer chooses randomly. After choosing a photo of your choise is presented and the value of the select list is also changed.

My problem is that the image doesn't always change, but only when the computer randomizes a number and only in Chrome. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/yotamoo/cr8s8/) a link to jsFiddle, also I'll provide my code here.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Rock-paper-scissers</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script src="rps.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
html{
    min-height: 100%;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
    font: 100.01% "Trebuchet MS",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#93e1d1), to(#d4c87c));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #93e1d1, #d4c87c); 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #93e1d1, #d4c87c);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
}
div#Container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div#InnerLeft {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
div#InnerRight {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

div#Footer {
    clear: both;
}
div#notes {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
select {
    background: transparent;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 220px;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 0px;
    height: 34px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Container">
<img src="images/header.png">
<div id="InnerLeft">
<img src="images/uno.png"><br>
<select id="p1" onchange="change('p1','rpsleft')">
<option value=0>Choose your weapon</option>
<option value=1>Rock</option>
<option value=2>Paper</option>
<option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>
<p><img src="images/rpsL.png" id="rpsleft"></p>
</div>
<div id="InnerRight">
<img src="images/dos.png"><br>
<select id="p2" onchange="change('p2','rpsright')">
<option value=0>Choose your weapon</option>
<option value=1>Rock</option>
<option value=2>Paper</option>
<option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>
<p><img src="images/rps.png" id="rpsright"></p>
</div>
<div id="Footer">
<img src="images/andale.png" id="andale" onclick="rps(document.getElementById('p1').value,document.getElementById('p2').value)"
onMouseOver="document.getElementById('andale').src='images/andale2.png'"
onMouseOut="document.getElementById('andale').src='images/andale.png'">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
// JavaScript Document
function reset() {
    document.getElementById('p1').value = 0;
    document.getElementById('p2').value = 0;
    document.getElementById('rpsleft').src="images/rpsL.png"
    document.getElementById('rpsright').src="images/rps.png"
    return;
}

function change(player,image) {
    var icon = document.getElementById(player).value;
    image = document.getElementById(image)
    switch (parseInt(icon)) {
        case 1: 
            if (player == 'p1')
                image.src="images/rockL.png";
            else 
                image.src="images/rock.png";
            break;
        case 2: 
            if (player == 'p1')
                image.src="images/paperL.png";
            else 
                image.src="images/paper.png";
            break;
        case 3: 
            if (player == 'p1')
                image.src="images/scissorsL.png";
            else 
                image.src="images/scissors.png";
            break;
    }
    return;
}

function getValue(player) {
    var rand = player;
    if (rand == 0) {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 1;
    }
    return rand;
}

function rps(player1,player2) {
    var p1 = getValue(player1);
    var p2 = getValue(player2);

    document.getElementById('p1').value = p1;
    document.getElementById('p2').value = p2;

    change('p1','rpsleft');
    change('p2','rpsright');
    if (p1 == p2) {
        alert("It's a tie!");
        reset();
        return;
    }

    var sum = parseInt(p1) + parseInt(p2);
    var winner;
    switch(sum) {
        case 3:
            (p1 == 2) ? winner = '1' : winner = '2';
            break;
        case 4:
            (p1 == 1) ? winner = '1' : winner = '2';
            break;
        case 5:
            (p1 == 3) ? winner = '1' : winner = '2';
            break;  
        default:
            alert("There was an error");        
    }
    alert("Player " + winner + " is the winner");
    reset();
    return;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle won't work with non-absolute url values.

Comment: You haven't got a change function defined in your fiddle, but it's there in your inline event handler.